# Do I need to restart nservicebus host processes after changing my license file?

Tags: nservicebus

Like the title says: I'm wondering if I need to restart my NServicebus-based services after replacing the NServicebus license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no!

NSB won't reload the license file if you replace it on disk, so you do need to restart the service, but on the other hand the expired license won't affect the quality of the service.

Comment: ah, so I can just do it during the next maintenance cycle without impacting services? Thats good news - thanks!